# mail attachment contains corrupt file

Tags: c#, .net

while sending email using C#, I am getting this issue.

Code

```
//profileUploadControl is my file upload control
    Attachment fileattach = new Attachment(profileUploadControl.PostedFile.InputStream, savedfilename,profileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType);
```

I am using this fileattach object as a parameter to send email function and
it is sending email but file is corrupted , no content in that file. Is something, i am missing here. Any help is appreciated.

please note that this code is working fine if i saved the file in server and access that path in file attach.
sample :

```
 profileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/en/companyProfiles/") + savedfilename);
  Attachment fileattach = new Attachment(Server.MapPath("~/en/companyProfiles/") + savedfilename);
```

but i don't want to save the file.

Comment: We need more details ...

Comment: Is the FileUpload control within an UpdatePanel parhaps?

Comment: savedfilename might have wrong extension, does it work with new Attachment(profileUploadControl.PostedFile.InputStream, profileUploadControl.PostedFile.FileName, profileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType); instead?

Comment: i also tried new Attachment(profileUploadControl.PostedFile.InputStream, profileUploadControl.PostedFile.FileName,profileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType); but no luck

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8351669/596758